# css - vertical nested menu - can't get the nested styles right, it makes a bigger rectangle

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make a vertical menu, but everytime when i show the sub menu on hover, it expands the previous element, making a 'bigger box'. I have no idea how to style that.
Dont want to use some jquery plugin if there is an css solution. I have also bootstrap3, but there is no support for nested dropdowns, dropdowns inside dropdowns ... the nested ones did not open...

JSFiddle link:  `http://jsfiddle.net/WqW5j/`

index.html

```
 <div class="nav">
 <ul class="main">
 <li><a href="">1</a></li>
 <li><a href="">2</a></li>
 <li>
   <a href="">3</a>
   <ul class="sub">
    <li><a href="">3-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">3-2</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li><a href="">3-2-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">3-2-2</a>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li><a href="">3-2-2-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">3-2-2-2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

css

```
        .main{
            list-style: none;
            padding:0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        .main li{
            background-color:#f1f1f1;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 5px;
            float:left;
            clear:both;
        }
        .main li:hover{
            background-color:#d8d8d8;
        }

          .main .sub{
            display: none;
          }
          .sub > li > .sub{
            display: none;
          }

          .main > li:hover > .sub:nth-of-type(1){
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            left: 20px;
            top:-30px;
            list-style: none;
            float:left;
            width: 100px;
            clear: both;
          }

          .sub > li:hover > .sub{
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            left: 20px;
            top:-30px; 
            list-style: none;
            float:left;
            width: 100px;
          }
```

Comment: JSFiddle please but use of `position:absolute` on your submenus woudl be the answer, I suspect.

Comment: Oh...and bootstrap DOES support Dropdown navs: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav

Comment: added link to jsfiddle, updated to use absolue, but then i have a problem with positioning the elements. In bootstrap i tried a dropdown, that has a dropdown inside, but the most inner one did not open when i clicked it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the nested menu work make all the `li` items `position:relative` and make the `ul` displayed on hover as `position:absolute`.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/pKmd5/)

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
 <ul class="main">
     <li><a href="">1</a>
         <ul class="sub">
             <li><a href="">1-1</a>
                 <ul class="sub">
                     <li><a href="">1-1-1</a></li>
                     <li><a href="">1-2-1</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href="">1-2</a>
                 <ul class="sub">
                     <li><a href="">1-2-1</a></li>
                     <li><a href="">1-2-2</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="">2</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main{
    list-style: none;
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  .main li{
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
  }
  .main li:hover{
   background-color:#d8d8d8;
  }

  .main .sub{
    display: none;
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:0;
    width:auto;
  }

.main .sub li{
    float:none;
}

.main > li:hover > .sub{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:100%;
}

.sub li:hover .sub{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:100%;
}
```